# Run relatively complex find|xargs command from a remote server

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a command that I can run without any issues on a Linux server (let's call it server1).

Here it is

```
myuser@server1:  find -L /data* -type d -maxdepth 2 | xargs -d $'\n' sh -c 'for arg do echo "$arg" $(stat -f -L -c %T  "$arg") ; done'
```

This lists all the directories 2 levels deep in directories tree of server1 and shows associated file systems for each of them.

Now what I want to do is to run exact same command from a bash script that resides on a remote server (let's call it server2) after ssh-ing to server1, but have the output written to a file on server2.
Basically do something like below

```
myuser@server2: ssh "myuser@server1"  "find -L /data* -type d -maxdepth 2 | xargs -d $'\n' sh -c 'for arg do echo "$arg" $(stat -f -L -c %T  "$arg") ; done'" >output.txt
```

However I can't seem to find the right syntax for this. I think the command above does variables expansion incorrectly. Could you please help?

Thank you,
-Grigor

Comment: Use a heredoc to feed your commands to stdin of `ssh`. Easier to deal with the quoting. You could also do this using `find -exec` instead of the piping to xargs and stat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using xargs and pipe, how about rearranging the command:

```bash
ssh myuser@server1 \
'for d in $(find -L ~/data* -type d -maxdepth 2); do echo "$d $(stat -f -L -c %T $d)"; done'
```

Comment: Thanks Hai Vu, this have worked. I also managed to achive the same with %n option of stat, so we can do something like this ssh myuser@server1 'find -L '/data*' -type d -maxdepth 2 -exec stat -f -L -c "%n %T"   {}  \;'

Answer (score 0):

The string you give to ssh as a remote command is subject to normal parsing on the local machine before it gets sent to the remote machine for reparsing and execution. To simplify your example a little:

```
# prints the numbers 1 2 3
for arg in 1 2 3 ; do echo $arg ; done
# prints three empty lines, assuming $arg is unset in your local environment
ssh user@remotehost "for arg in 1 2 3 ; do echo $arg ; done"
```

What happened here? When bash evaluates your command line in the second example, it substitutes `$arg` for its value following normal parameter expansion rules before it runs `ssh`. This means the command that actually gets sent through to the remote machine is `for arg in 1 2 3 ; do echo ; done`.

There's a lot of good advice for fixing this on the [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/096). A couple summary examples:

1. Manual requoting. In my very simple example you can use single quotes instead of double quotes to protect the string from being evaluated. Your code is a little more complex since you have embedded single quotes, so you would have to handle escaping them by replacing every single quote with `'\''`.
2. Use stdin instead of the command line. A heredoc for example will let you pass commands to the remote machine with less manual formatting required.
3. Use a tool like `printf %q` if the remote shell is Bash. This will format a string in such a way that it is safe to be evaluated twice like it is in the `ssh` case.

Comment: Hi tjm3772, thanks for your response. I accepted Hai Vu's answer because it solved my issue. I understand that there is a way of formatting the string in a way that the command starts working as expected (hence the question), but I was expecting a well formatted example as was presented by Hai Vu. It would really be helpful if you could post your solution for my original question because what Hei Vu presented is a workaround, not the answer to original question, so if we have an answer to original question, I can change accepted answer.